# MYSQL Full text search with subquery

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'd like to use the single result of SELECT Query for Full text search.

Here's the the sample select query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(meaning) SEPARATOR ' ') as translation 
FROM knowledge_management.tbl_word_meaning 
WHERE word = 'Bet' and locale = 'en'
```

[image]

This is my final query which gets the result of SELECT query as search text.

```
SELECT * 
FROM knowledge_management.tbl_article 
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ((
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(meaning) SEPARATOR ' ') as translation 
    FROM knowledge_management.tbl_word_meaning 
    WHERE word = 'Bet' and locale = 'en'
    ) IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Now i'd like to use the result in the full text search, but it doesn't give me a good result.

Works fine when added hardcoded text ''

[image]

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you do `MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Wager Stake Punt' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`?

Comment: @Barmar yes it gives expected result with hardcoded 'Wager Stake Punt'

Answer (score 1):

Test

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM knowledge_management.tbl_article a
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(meaning) SEPARATOR ' ') as translation 
             FROM knowledge_management.tbl_word_meaning 
             WHERE word = 'Bet' and locale = 'en' ) b
WHERE MATCH(a.name) AGAINST (b.translation IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

---

**UPDATE**

> SQL Error [1210] [HY000]: Incorrect arguments to AGAINST – str028

That's true ([MATCH() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)):

> The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

If so then dynamic SQL seems to be the only option.

<kbd>[**Modelling DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf13de45a76c7838438b106ff579ed08)</kbd>

Comment: It gives an error. Incorrect arguments to AGAINST
I think the b.translation became multiple values as we cross join this from other table

Comment: SQL Error [1210] [HY000]: Incorrect arguments to AGAINST